# Grails war command doesn't set the environment

Tags: grails, tomcat6, war

I run an app using embedded container using `grails run-app -Dgrails.env=myenv` and it works fine.  I then do `grails war -Dgrails.env=myenv` deploy it on a Tomcat 6 server and it doesn't work.  I get a bunch of log4J errors that go away once I add log4j jars to Tomcat lib's directory.  The lo4j errors now go away.  I am left with:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive qkr2.war
Sep 7, 2013 11:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 7, 2013 11:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/mk2] startup failed due to previous errors
```

But there are no previous errors.  So I haven't a clue what could be wrong.
Or what to do next.  Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html, the environment comes BEFORE the "war" part of the command, so that could be it.  i.e. the command should read:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=myenv war
```

Check the logging to see what environment grails thinks it's starting under.   Otherwise, I'd try adding the environment variable at Tomcat startup, rather than building different wars for different environments.

This all presumes that the logging config is correct in this myenv environment.  If not, then I can't tell you why it's not starting without more of the logging available.

Answer (score 1):

When you see "SEVERE: Error listenerStart" deploying to Tomcat, look at the log files. In general you'll find that the error is in stacktrace.log or localhost.2013-09-07.log (the date part of the file name may be different of course).